# Is this as inefficient as it feels?

Tags: javascript

I have a webpage with two lists.  A source list (represented by availableThings) populated by a search, and items that the user has selected (selectedThings).  I want to maintain a unique list of selectedThings, so I want to remove already selected things from the list of available things.  In my code snippet below, `data.AvailableThings` is populated from the server and has no knowledge of user-selected things.  The user can select up to 3 items, ergo `selectedThings.items` will contain no more than 3 items.  `availableThings.items` can potentially be a few thousand.

After `availableThings.items` gets populated, I feed it into ICanHaz for the HTML generation.  FWIW, I'm using jQuery for drag behavior between the lists, but the question is jQuery-agnostic.

```
[... jQuery AJAX call snipped ...]
success: function (data) {

    availableThings.items = [];

    for (var thing in data.AvailableThings) {
        var addToList = true;

        for (var existing in selectedThings.items) {
            if (existing.Id === thing.Id) {
                addToList = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (addToList) {
            availableThings.items.push(thing);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `ICanHaz` ? ... Is this integrated with some form of LOLCODE by chance?

Comment: ICanHaz is a templating library that combines Mustache and jQuery templ: http://icanhazjs.com

Comment: Is there any sort of order to the AvailableThings list coming from the server?

Comment: @Jim: not really, at least not in the context of what `selectedThings.items` may contain.  Since `AvailableThings` is populated on a search, the user can completely change the search criteria and get a new list of `AvailableThings` back.  As long as they haven't used their three selected things, this is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: Does a for-in loop work differently in icanhaz?  Normally "thing" would contain the item's key/index, and not the item itself.

Comment: @James, no, and your comment helped me figure out why that construct wasn't working as a `foreach` in the server language was.  Wish I could give you more than the +1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If n is the count of available things and m is the count of selected things, then this is O(n * m) whereas if you hashed by ID, you could turn this into O(n + m).

```
var existingIds = {};

for (var existing in selectedThings.items) {
  existingIds[existing.Id] = existingIds;
}

availableThings.items = [];
for (var thing in data.AvailableThings) {
    if (existingIds[thing.Id] !== existingIds) {
        availableThings.items.push(thing);
    }
}
```

Comment: What would this look like?  I need to keep at least `availableThings.items` as an array (granted, of hashes) for my templating library.

Answer (score 1):

If there is some sort of order (ordered by ID, name, or any field) to the data coming from the server, you could just do a binary search for each of the items in the selected set, and remove them if they are found. This would reduce it to O(m log n) for a dataset of n items where selection of m items is allowed. Since you've got it fixed at 3, it would essentially be O(log n).